# Is Clubhouse chatting room deleted, if yes could someone create a new one?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

I don't see the chatting room the clubhouse if it has been deleted, can we create one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/the-clubhouse) and [Sports News](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29021/sports-news) chat rooms are still open! Perhaps you were seeing rooms from another site instead. You can favorite the room to keep from losing it again, or you can always go to the [site tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=sports.stackexchange.com) on Chat.SE and search for "Sports".

Or, to get there from here, you can go through the Stack Exchange menu:
[image: click "Stack Exchange" in the upper left, then click the "chat" link]

Comment: Sir it was not showing on sidebar as it used to do, so I thought maybe it has been deleted. Thanks for telling me the way.

Comment: There is code in the Stack Exchange software stack which decides which chat rooms to show, and sometimes that decides not to show any of our chatrooms, probably because they're not very active.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I was told that whether or not some rooms associated with the site are shown in the sidebar depends also on the amount of space (and so indirectly on number and length of answers). See [this comment by Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287504/are-chat-rooms-in-the-sidebar-shown-for-unregistered-and-low-rep-users#comment932856_287505).